# What OpenCV method can I use to denoise an image like the Napa filter in Windows Photos?

Tags: opencv, image-processing

I am trying to imitate the Napa image filter in the Windows Photos app with OpenCV. I have tried methods such as fastNlMeansDenoising and edgePreservingFilter, but they did not produce similar results. I am only concerned about the denoising and not the color change.
Here is an example image before and after application of the filter:
[Original](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6bmzU.jpg)

[With Napa filter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UaYju.jpg)

Comment: Did you look at the documentation? https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d5/d69/tutorial_py_non_local_means.html

Comment: Thanks. I was able to get it to work  by tweaking the values of  templateWindowSize and searchWindowSize parameters.

Comment: Maybe you should write your own answer then, in case it could help others.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get a sharp image with lesser noise by using a low value of templateWindowSize and a high value of searchWindowSize parameters of the fastNlDenoisingColored method.